# Fetching the attribute value of parents previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(() => {
  $("#responseType").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).parent('div').prev().attr('data-type');
    console.log(link); 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="documentWrapper" class="document-wrapper" tabindex="-1"><div class="document ui-selectable">
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">What are your short and long-term goals? How do you plan to use your MBA?</div>
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Your short-term goals should be concrete and achievable, and your long-term goals should fit well with your passions and personality.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">How will you contribute to our campus?</div>  
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Mention clubs and leaderships opportunities that you are interested in, and highlight any unique passions that you would bring to the student body.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question1">What is your biggest strength? Your biggest weakness?</div>
  <div id="kbSelectionMenu">
            <label >
                <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="questionType" value="question">
                <label for="questionType">Question</label>
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="responseType" value="response">
                <label for="responseType" class="ui-selectee">Response</label>
            </label>

        </div></div>

  <p class="Normal DocDefaults  data-selection ui-selectee">&nbsp;</p></div></div>
```

In the above html there are radio buttons. On click of the radio button I want to get the attribute "data-type" of the div which is previous to the parent div of the radio button.

We tried the above Jquery code.  This code return the attribute "data-type" of current div and not previous.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) select parent of element but you need to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to selecting first element that matches the selector from set of parents.

```
$("#responseType").click(function(){
  var link = $(this).closest('div').prev().attr('data-type');
  console.log(link); 
});
```

```js
$("#responseType").click(function(){
  var link = $(this).closest('div').prev().attr('data-type');
  console.log(link); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="documentWrapper" class="document-wrapper" tabindex="-1"><div class="document ui-selectable">
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">What are your short and long-term goals? How do you plan to use your MBA?</div>
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Your short-term goals should be concrete and achievable, and your long-term goals should fit well with your passions and personality.</div>
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">How will you contribute to our campus?</div>  
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Mention clubs and leaderships opportunities that you are interested in, and highlight any unique passions that you would bring to the student body.</div>
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question1">What is your biggest strength? Your biggest weakness?</div>
  <div id="kbSelectionMenu">
    <label >
      <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="questionType" value="question">
      <label for="questionType">Question</label>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="responseType" value="response">
      <label for="responseType" class="ui-selectee">Response</label>
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p class="Normal DocDefaults  data-selection ui-selectee">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) matches the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements. In your HTML structure the parent of the radio is the *label* element not the *div* element you are looking for.

Try with [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) which matches the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the *DOM* tree.

***Please Note:*** It is better to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get/set the value at the named data store of an element.

```
var link = $(this).closest('div').prev().data('type');
```

```js
$(() => {
  $("#responseType").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().get(0).nodeName); // LABEL
    var link = $(this).closest('div').prev().data('type');
    console.log(link);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="documentWrapper" class="document-wrapper" tabindex="-1"><div class="document ui-selectable">
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">What are your short and long-term goals? How do you plan to use your MBA?</div>
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Your short-term goals should be concrete and achievable, and your long-term goals should fit well with your passions and personality.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">How will you contribute to our campus?</div>  
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Mention clubs and leaderships opportunities that you are interested in, and highlight any unique passions that you would bring to the student body.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question1">What is your biggest strength? Your biggest weakness?</div>
  <div id="kbSelectionMenu">
      <label >
          <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="questionType" value="question">
          <label for="questionType">Question</label>
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="responseType" value="response">
            <label for="responseType" class="ui-selectee">Response</label>
        </label>

    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="Normal DocDefaults  data-selection ui-selectee">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

If you really want to use `parent()` then you have to go to another level up in the *DOM* tree:

```
var link = $(this).parent().parent('div').prev().data('type');
```

```js
$(() => {
  $("#responseType").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).parent().parent('div').prev().data('type');
    console.log(link);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="documentWrapper" class="document-wrapper" tabindex="-1"><div class="document ui-selectable">
  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">What are your short and long-term goals? How do you plan to use your MBA?</div>
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Your short-term goals should be concrete and achievable, and your long-term goals should fit well with your passions and personality.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question">How will you contribute to our campus?</div>  
  <div class="element-selection response-selection ui-selectee" data-type="response">Mention clubs and leaderships opportunities that you are interested in, and highlight any unique passions that you would bring to the student body.</div>

  <div class="element-selection question-selection ui-selectee" data-type="question1">What is your biggest strength? Your biggest weakness?</div>
  <div id="kbSelectionMenu">
      <label >
          <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="questionType" value="question">
          <label for="questionType">Question</label>
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="import-type" id="responseType" value="response">
            <label for="responseType" class="ui-selectee">Response</label>
        </label>

    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="Normal DocDefaults  data-selection ui-selectee">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to `$(this).closest()` if you want to use `#kbSelectionMenu`